# Better Syntax for $.inArray() Loop Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am attempting to use a loop with $.inArray. Basically, I have information that I'm looping through and I need to take a piece of the information and add it to an array. If that information already exists in the area (there are duplicates, three of the same, four of the same, etc. all the way up to 12 instances of the same data), I'm appending a number to the end of the data to determine which duplicate it is. Here's my code:

```
var subject_name_original = subject_name;    

if ($.inArray(subject_name, subject_array) !== -1){
    subject_name = subject_name_original + '2';
    if ($.inArray(subject_name, subject_array) !== -1){
        subject_name = subject_name_original + '3';
        if ($.inArray(subject_name, subject_array) !== -1){
            subject_name = subject_name_original + '4';
        }
     }
}

subject_array.push(subject_name);
```

This is looping all the way up to 12 instances so you can see that it's not very efficient the way it's written. I'm wanting to use a counter variable to increment the appended number but not sure how to use inArray in a loop like that.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var subjectCounter = 1;
var originalSubjectName = subjectName;
while (subjectArray.indexOf(subjectName) !== -1) { // $.inArray is the same as this
    subjectCounter += 1;
    subjectName = originalSubjectName + subjectCounter;
}
subjectArray.push(subjectName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If subject_array is not sorted, sort it first. Then you should only need to visit each item once.

```
var sorted = subject_array.sort();
var subject_counter = 1;
var subject_name_original = subject_name;

for (var i = sorted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (sorted[i] == subject_name) {
    subject_counter++;
    subject_name = subject_name_original + subject_counter;
  };
};

subject_array.push(subject_name);
```

Comment: Ignore me! I forgot that you have up to 12 instances which won't be sorted properly.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work (not tested) :

```
var i = 1;
var subject_name_original = subject_name;
while (++i < 13) { // at first loop, i = 2
    if ($.inArray(subject_name, subject_array) !== -1) {
        subject_name = subject_name_original + i;
    } else {

        // $.inArray() failed beyound the second loop :

        if (i > 3) {
            subject_name = subject_name_original + (i - 1);
            subject_array.push(subject_name);
        }

        // $.inArray() failed at second loop (i = 3) :

        else if (i > 2) {
            subject_name = subject_name_original;
            subject_array.push(subject_name);
        }

        // Does nothing if $.inArray() failed at first loop.

        break;
    }
}
```